# multiple containers error in Arquillian

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss-weld, jboss-arquillian

I am installing Arquillian in a project which utilizes weld CDI and JPA and I am trying to use embedded GlassFish container (I read that Weld embedded container is not supporting JPA).

I have added GlassFishContainer in my `pom.xml` but I am getting an error message when I running the test cases. Here id the Error message:

```
 Multiple service implementations found for interface 
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeployableContainer. 
org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer,    
org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.WeldEEMockContainer
```

It seems that I have both Weld embedded container and glassFilsh. I double checked my `pom.xml` , I have just embedded glassfish. I couldn't find any sign of Weld embedded container. Any idea?!

Comment: You may want to run `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is bringing in the Weld-EE container adapter into your classpath. I suspect that you have two profiles enabled at the same time, but it could also be transitive dependencies.

Comment: Agreed.  You can have only one container on your build classpath.  It's also possible that you're not using profiles, but instead just pulled in both dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error as well while setting up Arquillian with an embedded Tomcat-8 in IntelliJ with Maven.

Here is my working (for an example project) POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>arquillilan.tomcat.test</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillianTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>arquillianTest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler>3.7</version.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler>
    <version.weld_servlet>1.1.9.Final</version.weld_servlet>
    <version.arquillian>1.1.5.Final</version.arquillian>
    <version.tomcat>8.5.57</version.tomcat>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- org.jboss.arquillian -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.container/arquillian-container-test-spi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-spi</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testenricher-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testenricher-resource</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- org.apache.tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.tomcat}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${version.tomcat}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
        <!--  2.0.0-beta-4 is not working  ** we are using old version -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.weld_servlet}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.171</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.40</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.container/arquillian-tomcat-embedded-8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-embedded-8</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-common</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

I´m using Intellij and configured a "Tomcat Embedded 8.x: AruillianTest".  After starting the test I got the exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not add a default container to registry because multiple instances of org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeployableContainer found on classpath (candidates are: org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.embedded.TomcatEmbeddedConfiguration, org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.embedded_8.TomcatConfiguration)

The problem was caused by the auto-configuration made by Intellij. [intellij_arquillian_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSR1.png) shows the path you have to take to address the error.

1 - click on "Edit configuration" -> it will open 2

2 - choose the embedded Tomcat you want to use (Tomcat 8 in my case) and click on 3 which will open  4

4 - the dependencies (5) are clickable. Double-clicking will open 6.

6 - choose your version to be exactly the same as in your pom. I'm using the 1.0.1.Final in my pom but my test-container was configured with 1.0.0.CR7 (made for this screenshot; normally its 'RELEASE'). Changing this to 1.0.1.FINAL resolved the error and the test could run.

Answer (score 0):

Delete one of the container from maven local repository. The default location for maven local repository is `$HOME/.m2/repository/`.

Try deleting `org/jboss/arquillian/container/glassfish.embedded_3_1` if you would like to run your tests with Weld Embedded Server else delete `org/jboss/arquillian/container/weld.ee.embedded_1_1`.

The reason being, both the Jars implement the same interface and arquillian cannot decide which one to use.

Comment: Even deleting `~/.m2/repository/` didn't help in my case. I doubt the Maven cache has any influence on this issue and if it would, it'd be a bug.